# Is there a standard height in lines for a drop cap?

Tags: typography, lettering

There is a package in LaTeX called `lettrine`, which allows you to use a drop cap.  You can check an example [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf)

I want to know how many lines of space should I give it for a one column technical document.

According to my friend designers, it's usually a rule to do everything by 3, so I did:

[image]

But for some reason I began to think that maybe the `S` is just too big (because of the "Chapter 1" and "Introduction").

So I also went with 2 lines:

[image]

Which one should I prefer?

## Latest version

[image]

Comment: I see your point @Dominic, but as I stated in the question, it is intended for a technical document (PhD thesis).  I would also like to remark there is no template, because I'm the one actually doing it (so sticking to the template or asking to the supervisor is not an option).  Perhaps my question could be rephrased as: which one is more esthetically beautiful? Which one would you prefer to read?

Comment: We try to stay away from simple opinions, and rather have them backed up like 'the second is better because of x, y and z' instead of just 'the second one is better' so we need a basis to judge it on. Which one looks more appropriate in a technical document? would be a little bit less subjective. Readability is a good basis to, but isn't much of an issue here. For what it's worth I think the second looks more balanced as its not so huge, but that's a subjective opinion. :)

Comment: @Dominic Assuming I go with #2, I guess I should stick to that format for the whole document, right?

Comment: Definitely, whichever one you choose you should stay consistent throughout the rest.

Comment: And my subjective opinion is that two lines looks like a mistake. Three is categorically on purpose. I prefer three.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum What doesn't convince me is the relationship of the letter with the "chapter 1" and "Introduction", or do you feel they are OK?

Comment: @MarioS.E. Those two lines are the wrong size in relation to each other; the sizes should be reversed. And I'd center both of them and possibly italicize Introduction. That will give the drop cap more independence and should eliminate the visual confusion you're feeling between it and Introduction.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Please bear in mind that my abstract, list of publications, Table of contents, table of figures, etc. follow the same formatting principles as "Introduction"... so if I were to change it to `center`, it would happen the same with all the other chapters of my thesis.  Would it be OK?

Comment: @MarioS.E. More than likely, but we've now reached the point where it's something I'd have to see in context.

Comment: Context is everything, but Lauren is suggesting the the heading type sizes need to reflect the hierarchical structure of the document. Usually, this means top level is bigger.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Could you please take a look at the latest version?

Comment: @horatio Could you please take a look at the latest version?

Comment: Looks good to me. Note that most universities have departmental style guides for publications, especially for doctoral review. Make sure you follow whatever is required for submission (if applicable).

Comment: @MarioS.E. WORLDS better. (Isn't it "bipedal" locomotion? [/proofreader] )

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I have no idea hehehehe, I'm not an English native speaker.  I did a fast google search and I found biped exists, but so does bipedal. I'll have to take your word on this one :), thanks

Comment: @MarioS.E. "Biped" is the noun (humans are bipeds; we have two feet). "Bipedal" is the adjective, in this case modifying locomotion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moment you create a drop cap, you also create an implied box for it to sit in. Its edges are defined by the text lines. In this case, the lines spacing you have used makes for a very awkward white gap below the 2-line drop capital. The 'S' looks as if it's trying to grab on to the lowercase 'u' to prevent itself from falling into the gaping hole under it.

With the 3-line drop cap, the space below is much smaller in proportion to the 'S', so it looks well anchored and stable.

Comment: Your point about implied space is good, but you could amplify it: the second and third lines of text to the right of the three-line drop cap line up with each other, but the second line to the right of the two-line drop cap has nothing to line up with.